# Can you solve this thing that i was asked in php interview?

Tags: php

Write a function in **php** to find out the number of jumps the prisoner makes to escape from the jail.

A prisoner escapes from the jail by jumping over a wall. He can jump *x* meters of height, but after every jump he slips *y* meters.

The function should take **four arguments** which are:

1. Max height he can jump
2. Number of meters he slips down the wall
3. Height of the wall
4. Number of walls

For example: (**10,1,11,2**):

This means that the prisoner can jump **10** meters in *height*.
He *slips down* **1** meter after every jump he makes.
*Wall height* is **11** meters.
There are **2** *walls*.

The **output** of this question should be : **4** (my guess)

Explanation: 
In his **first jump** reaches 10 meter height but slip down 1 meter so the effective jump height was 9 meter,then in the **second jump** he starts from that 9 meter point and makes one more and successfully manages to climb the first wall. To climb the second wall he has to go through the same process again.

I am not good in math. That's why I couldn't figure out how to put them together and make an equation out of them.

This question was asked when I was applying as fresher php developer. Do you think asking this kind of question to a fresher was justified?

Comment: Writing the code would be relatively simple, I think the main focus of that exercise was to determine whether you can build an algorithm around a set of inputs and requirements.

Comment: The catch here is to recognize that jumping 10 meters then slipping down 1 meter is not the same as jumping 9 meters. It's not unreasonable to solve this by an algorithm rather than a single mathematical equation because of this. And yes, if you claimed any knowledge of PHP it's not an unreasonable question.

Comment: Anyone that claims to know a programming language that has user-defined functions and loops but has trouble with this question should reconsider their career path. Just an observation.

Comment: I'm fine if a newbie brute-forces the solution. But any developer that couldn't solve this in a reasonable time (<10 minutes) is someone that, if hired, is going to be in my office every dang time any kind of challenge comes up (usually 5-10 times a day), asking me what to do, and that wastes my time to the point that they're a net loss. No hire.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't really test your php knowledge but definitely tests your problems solving skills. I'd say it is a pretty reasonable question to ask at an interview.

```
function returnCounts($jump,$slip,$height,$walls)
{
   $count = 0;

   while(true)
   {
      $count++;
      $height -= $jump;
      if ($height <= 0)
      {
          return $walls * $count;
      }
      else
      {
          $height += $slip;
      }
   }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but something like this should work

Comment: Just a minor nit-pick: The function needs a name.

Comment: @xbonex- thanx bro your function works.And yes i whole heartedly agree that the question is more about the problem solving ability.

Comment: echo returnCounts(10,11,11,2);

Comment: @Consciousness: that would be an infinite loop due to the value of the parameters (slip > jump). I suppose as a fail-safe, there could be an if condition that `if $count > 100, break and return null;`

Comment: I know; I just decided to point it out. Also, if slip > jump but jump > wall it could still work in theory

Comment: @Consciousness Not sure if you're already aware, but it's generally encouraged to place code inside SO comments between backticks `. If you are, disregard this, but otherwise start getting friendly with the backticks :)

Comment: Wasn't aware you could do that in comments.

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

I would guess they wanted you to figure out that there is a way to do this *without writing a loop* to "simulate" the prisoner's escape.

Obviously if there were no "slip" it would be trivial --

```
return ceil($wallheight / $jumpheight) * $walls;
```

The slip seems to throw a wrench into this equation, but when you consider edge cases it becomes apparent that it can be easily dealt with.  What happens if he jumps 5 but slips 4?  Suppose a wall height of 10.  Jump to 5, slip to 1.  Jump to 6, slip to 2.  Jump to 7, slip to 3.  Jump to 8, slip to 4.  Jump to 9, slip to 5.  Jump and escape.

So, we can simply remove the jump height from the wall, and then divide the rest by the difference between his jump and his slip (rounding up).  Don't forget (as I did!) to add that "last jump" back in!

```
function count_jumps($jumpheight, $slipheight, $wallheight, $walls) {
    if($jumpheight > $wallheight) return $walls;
    else return (ceil(($wallheight - $jumpheight) / ($jumpheight - $slipheight)) + 1) * $walls;
}
```

Edit: Fixed.

Edit 2: Note that this function could possibly produce errors or negative results, but they will all be in situations where the return value would be infinite or undefined (slip >= jump).  In an interview situation, you should ask your interviewer how they would want those cases handled.

Comment: You're low by one jump per wall. In other words, you forgot to count the last jump, which got you over the wall. Also, once you fix that, you don't need that `if()` test at all.

Comment: Actually the if() is still needed, for prisoners who can super jump, or very short walls.

Answer (score 1):

With some basic algebra you can eliminate the need for any loops:

```
function findJumps($jump_height, $slip, $wall_height, $walls) {
    return $walls * ($jump_height > $wall_height) ? 1 : ceil(($wall_height - $slip) / ($jump_height - $slip));
}
```

Explanation:

For every jump the prisoner makes he gains `$jump_height` but loses `$slip` in elevation, so his change in elevation can be represented as `$jump_height - $slip`. To find how many jumps per wall simply divide the wall height by the change in elevation `$wall_height / ($jump_height - $slip)`. Since it's possible that the result of this isn't even, we have to round up with `ceil()` (Ex. if you jumped 2 feet and the wall was 3 feet high, you'd need to take two jumps to completely clear the wall). The simply multiply this by the number of walls he has to scale.

Comment: See MZB's comment: "The catch here is to recognize that jumping 10 meters then slipping down 1 meter is not the same as jumping 9 meters." Though it is true that you don't need a loop...

Comment: Incorrect. The slip only happens *after* the jump. If they manage to jump to the top then no slip happens.

Comment: Well, you slip down the other side and somehow survive, but we won't tell if you won't... ^_-

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Touché! I knew it was missing something obvious. Will fix.

Comment: echo findJumps(10,1,10,1); :P

Answer (score 1):

All of the current answers seem to neglect input checking, as some are susceptible to infinite loops.

To prevent this, do some error checking before you attempt to process the input. Here are the two versions I could come up with, the first uses a straightforward loop implementation, the second uses math.

Note: There may still be bugs, I haven't tested them 100%.

```
function escape( $max_height, $slip, $wall_height, $num_walls)
{
     // Check for infinite loop
     if( ($max_height - $slip) <= 0)
     {
         // Return a value to let caller know an error has occurred
         return -1;
     }
     $jumps = 0;
     while( $num_walls > 0)
     {
         $current_height = 0;
         do
         {
              $current_height += $max_height;
              $jumps++;
         } while( ($wall_height - $current_height) >= 0);
         $num_walls--;
     }
     $jumps = ($wall_height % $max_height == 0) ? ($jumps - 1) : $jumps;
     return $jumps;
}
```

And now, without loops:

```
function escape2( $max_height, $slip, $wall_height, $num_walls) 
{
    // Check for valid input
    if( ($max_height - $slip) <= 0)
    {
         return -1;
    }
    if( $wall_height <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    $jumps = ceil( abs( $wall_height - ($max_height - $slip)));
    return ($jumps == 0) ? $num_walls : ($jumps * $num_walls);
}
```

[Test them out](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fVZw3N), send me some bug reports. :)

Comment: Bug: `escape` doesn't always return a number.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone - Should be fixed, I added a number to the error checking return. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's analytic algorithmic task. 
 Pseudo code :

```
prisonBreak(x,y,z,t):
  loop t times:           // number of walls
    set x,y,z again for next iteration  //here or at the end.
    while(can jump):      // can jump = x<z where z is adjusted after each jump
      z=jump              // adjust remaining distance after jump.
      countJumps++        // increment jump count.
```