# Explanation of test case in the prisoner wall jump program

Tags: function, debugging, integer-arithmetic

This would be the general problem statement:

A prisoner escapes from the jail by jumping over N walls each with height of each wall given in an array. He can jump x meters of height, but after every jump he slips y meters due to some uncontrollable factors(wind, slippery wall, etc).

[Similar problem statement mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276448/can-you-solve-this-thing-that-i-was-asked-in-php-interview)

The programming task given was to debug a function which included four parameters -

```
NoOfJumps(int x, int y, int N, int Height[])
```

1. Number of meters he jumps
2. Number of meters he slips down the wall
3. Number of walls
4. Height of the walls as an array

The first test case was for parameters - (10, 1, 1, {10})

10 being the meters he jumps, 1 meter he slips down, Number of walls being 1, and height of the wall being 10. Now:

effectiveJump = x - y = 9.

So he would have to jump twice to jump over the walls. So, **this function should return 2** (total number of jumps required to escape).

There was also another test case for the parameters - (3, 1, 5, {20,5,12,11,3})

3 being the meters he jumps, 1 meter he slips down, Number of walls being 5, and height of the walls given as 20m, 5m, 12m, 11m, 3m. Now:

effectiveJump = x - y = 2.

We were given **the output for the above parameter values as 24.**

`NoOfJumps(3, 1, 5, {20,5,12,11,3})`

I can't understand how this output value is obtained. How exactly are the walls arranged?

I can only think of one solution for the corner case, i.e, **when the person jumps over the wall**

(`when (x) > remaining height of the wall`),

**he should not slip down else I can't obtain the required solution.** 
For example, in the second test case at first wall, when the person is at 18m height, and he jumps 3m to 21m and doesn't slip down as he has crossed that wall. Next he starts jumping from 21 and not 20. The sequence of jumping would be :

0->2->4->6->8->10->12->14->16->18->21->23->26->28->30->32->34->36->39->41->43->45->47->50->53

Assuming walls at height, 20, 25, 37, 48, 51.

Is this a correct assumption for solving the problem?

Comment: do you have any more information? the to-be-debugged function could just be wrong. ... or the tests....

Comment: We had to debug the function and make it pass the test cases(more test cases might be hidden). After testing and compiling, I could see  the expected output and my output for the second test case. The expected output was 24 for that. In the debug function, we were provided with the following code : `totalJump += wallHeight[i]/effectiveJump` (originally it was `totalJump = +wallHeight[i]/effectiveJump`)

Comment: wallHeight refers to the array containing the heights of the wall. the totalJump was incremented for each iteration of the loop which ran 5 times (no of walls)

Comment: so you can reveal a testcase by success in the preceding one?

Comment: It was the only testcase (3, 1, 5, {20,5,12,11,3}) apart from the first example given(10, 1, 1, {10}), against which we could check if our code was working correctly.

Comment: is there a slight chance, that the task is just ... broken? ^^

Comment: I can only wonder that the 1st example given would be somehow not satisfactory to solve the problem. But that is all that I can do. It was asked as a question for qualification round of an well-established company. I think they might have tested it well before asking us this question.

Comment: it might also be a test for something else, to see how you approach the problem.

Comment: Yes, that can be possible too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C code on given case 2, will work for case 1 on changing the
parameters to (10,1,1,10).

```c
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int jump(int x,int y,int n,int z[]);
int jump(int x,int y,int n,int z[])
{
    int i, j, countjump, total = 0, extra = 0;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n%d\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\n%d", z[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        countjump = 1;
        z[j] = z[j] + (extra) - x;
        while (z[j] >= 0) {
            z[j] = z[j] + y;
            z[j] = z[j] - x;
            countjump = countjump + 1;
            if (z[j] < 0) {
                extra = z[j];
            }
        }
        total = (countjump + total);
    }
    return total;
}
void main()
{
    int res, manjump = 3, slip = 1, nwalls = 5;
    int wallheights[] = {20, 5, 12, 11, 3};
    clrscr();
    res = jump(manjump, slip, nwalls, wallheights);
    printf("\n\ntotal jumps:%d", res);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: That works well. Looks like you are assuming the walls to be vertical like me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one.

**Sample Code**

```
public static int calculateJumps(int X, int Y, int height[]) {
    int tn=0,n;
    for(int i=0; i<height.length; i++) {
        if(height[i]<=X) {
            tn+=1;
            continue;
        }
        n=((height[i]-X)/(X-Y));
        n+=height[i]-((X-Y)*n)==X?1:2;
        tn+=n;
    }
    return tn;
}
```

You need to pass only `X` , `Y` and `Array` than you can get you output.

Comment: Your code works for the second test case. But not for the first one where only one wall of height 10 is given. There the output shown is to be 2. The above code would give the output 1. Also, could you explain the statement where the n is incremented by 1 or 2 depending on the required condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You don't require the number of walls as it equals to size of array

```
public class Jump {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int jump = 3;
        int slip = 1;
        int[] hights = {20,5,12,11,3};

        int count = 0;
        for (int hight : hights) {
            int temp = hight - jump;
            if (temp >= 0) {
                count = count + temp / (jump - slip)+1;
            }
            if (temp % (jump - slip) > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider the first test case, where there is only one wall to jump of 10m and the slip is 1m. The code gives output 1 for it. It should display 2.

Comment: He will jump 10 m and cross the wall in first jump. He will not slip :)

Comment: That's what I thought too. But as I said, in the comment section of the question, "It was asked as a question for qualification round of an well-established company. I think they might have tested it well before asking us this question." They had given the two test cases. We had to complete the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. May not be optimized

$input1 = Jump Height

$input2 = Slipage

$input = Array of walls height

```
function GetJumpCount($input1,$input2,$input3)
{
    $jumps = 0;
    $wallsCrossed = 0;
    while($wallsCrossed != count($input3)){
        $jumps++;
        $input3[$wallsCrossed] = $input3[$wallsCrossed] - $input1;
        if($input3[$wallsCrossed] > 0){
            $input3[$wallsCrossed] = $input3[$wallsCrossed] + $input2;
        }else{
            $wallsCrossed++;
        }
    }
    return $jumps;
}
```

Comment: You are not testing for the 1st case. The number of jumps would be 1 (and not 2 as required) for the code written in this case. I have given my explanation for both the test cases. You need not provide me with the solution. I just want to know if my approach is right.

Comment: You did not try the code. Please do that first **echo GetJumpCount(10,1,[10]);**

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am explaining again. The number of jumps returned by this statement: **echo GetJumpCount(10,1,[10]);** **should be 2** and **not 1.** Clearly, your solution gives **output 1** which is not what I mentioned in the problem test case explanation.

Comment: And yes I did not try the code, because I tried it out for the 1st test case by hand and it was giving the wrong result.

Comment: Just to clearify, Why do you want the slippage for the first scenario even when the prisoner has reached the top of the wall ?

Comment: "It was asked as a question for qualification round of an well-established company. I think they might have tested it well before asking us this question." They had given the two test cases. We had to complete the function which would solve these test cases along with the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The walls come one after another. After jumping wall one the position should start from zero and not from the last jump height. For the first case the output should really be 1 as the height and jump are same. In the second test case, 24 is the right output. 
I've seen the exact same question on techgig contest. For the first test case the output should be 1. The test case had been explained by themselves where there is no slipping if the jump and height are same.

Comment: I see. But in our case, the test case had been clearly mentioned with output 2 and it was also explained as this would be the slippage and this would be the jump.

Answer (score 0):

check if this solves your problem

```py
def GetJumpCount(jump, slips, walls):
    """
    @jump:int, Height of 1 jump
    @slips:int, height of slip
    @walls:array, height of walls
    """
    jumps = []
    for wall_height in walls:
        wall_jump = 1
        wall_height -= jump
        while wall_height > 0:
            wall_height += slips
            wall_height -= jump
            wall_jump += 1
        jumps.append(wall_jump)
    return sum(jumps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic is here Plz check if this solves your problem.

```
package puzeels;

public class Jump
{
    int jump=6;
    int slip=1;
    int numberOfWals=4;
    int height[] ={21,16,10,5};

    static int count=0;
    int wallheight=0;

    private int findJump()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<height.length;i++)
        {             
            wallheight=height[i];
            while((wallheight>0))
            {
                count=count+1;
                wallheight=wallheight-(jump-slip);
                System.out.println(wallheight+"  "+count);
            }
            System.out.println("Out of while loop");
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        Jump obj = new Jump();
        int countOfJumps=obj.findJump();

        System.out.println("number of jumps is==>   "+countOfJumps);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving output 27 instead of 24 for the 2nd test case.

Answer (score 0):

I think 12 is a wrong answer, as I tried this code I got 11, last jump doesn`t have a slip:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    int T;
    int jcapacity, jslip, nwalls;

    //BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    T = sc.nextInt();
    jcapacity = sc.nextInt();
    jslip = sc.nextInt();
    nwalls = sc.nextInt();
    int [] wallHeightArr = new int [nwalls];

    for (int i = 0; i< nwalls; i++) {

        wallHeightArr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    sc.close();

    while(T-->0) {

        int distance = log(jcapacity,jslip,wallHeightArr);
        System.out.println(distance);
    }
}

private static int log(int jcapacity, int jslip, int[] wallHeightArr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int distance = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< wallHeightArr.length; i++) {

        int cHeight = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (wallHeightArr[i] - cHeight > jcapacity) {

            cHeight += (jcapacity - jslip);
            count++;
        }
        count++;
        distance += count;
    }

    return distance;
}
```

Comment: 12 wrong answer of which test case? Is it the height of the 3rd wall you are referring to in second test case? If that is the case, then I can say that this test case was provided as an example by the setter of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def jumpTheifCount(arr, X, Y):
    jump = 0
    remheight = 0

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if X == arr[i]:
            jump = jump + 1
            continue
        if X < arr[i]:
            jump = jump + 1
            remheight = arr[i] - X + Y
        if remheight > X:
            jump = jump + 1
            remheight = arr[i] - X + Y
        if remheight < X:
            jump = jump + 1
            continue
    return jump

arr = [11, 10, 10, 9]
X = 10
Y = 1

print(jumpTheifCount(arr, X, Y))
```

Comment: The answer mentioned doesn't work for the mentioned test cases. You can check the accepted solution if you have a similar query.